# When to observe model data when using Storyboards

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

Let's assume I have an address book App.
So from the address list I now push to a detail view like so:

1. User taps on cell in the master list
2. Segue `showDetail` is invoked
3. In `prepareForSegue:` I set the model object `contact` of my `ContactDetailViewController`
4. `viewWillAppear` I add an observer for `self.contact`
5. So now when the `contact` object changes in the background, the detail view will automatically be updated.
6. In `viewWillDisappear` I remove this observer (I guess it's clean because it is symetrical).

However, `viewWillAppear:` is called **after** I set the contact. So should I setup the KVO differently or simply call my `updateView` function in `viewWillAppear` which is a bit stupid because I want to get rid of those calls with KVO in the first place.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Keep the master table view in sync with the changes you make in the detail view?

Comment: @jrturton The `contact` object can be updated in the background. This is why I want to observe it. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `addObserver:...` you want to include the option `NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial`. This will cause KVO to send the equivalent of a `didChangeValueForKey:` notification (i.e. an "Initial" notification) in the same call that adds the observation. This should cause your view to update at that time.